# Query to count living population each year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a list of databases, about 10k rows, 1 row for each database. The table contains attributes for:

```
ServerId (int)
DBID (int)
DBName (varchar(255))
Createtime(datetime) 
LastCheckTime(datetime).
```

`LastCheckTime` is frequently updated until the database is removed on the SQL Server, and then it stops being updated.

I would like to count how many "living" databases there have been each year. If the `LastCheckTime < getdate()-1` then I assume it's alive and should be counted for each year from `Createtime` until `LastCheckTime` is more than 1 day.

The table resides in a SQL Server 2008R2 database. I can upgrade to SQL Server 2016 if it's easier to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you also post some sample along data along with expected result set?

Comment: It is supposed to be data for a graph to display how many "live" databases that exist each year:

ie:

year count
2001 500
2002 600
2003 800
2004 900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query returns the desired output:

```
CREATE TABLE [DB]
(
    ServerId INT,
    [DBID] INT,
    DBName varchar(255),
    Createtime DATETIME,
    LastCheckTime DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO [DB] VALUES
(1,1, 'DB1', '2010-09-10', '2013-09-01'),
(1,2, 'DB2',    '2010-09-10', GETDATE()),
(1,3, 'DB3',    '2010-09-12', GETDATE()),
(1,4, 'DB4',    '2011-09-13', GETDATE()),
(1,5, 'DB5',    '2011-09-10', GETDATE()),
(1,6, 'DB6',    '2013-09-10', GETDATE()),
(1,7, 'DB7',    '2014-09-10', GETDATE()),
(1,8, 'DB8',    '2015-09-10', GETDATE()),
(1,9, 'DB9',    '2016-09-10', GETDATE()),
(1,10, 'DB10',  '2017-09-10', GETDATE());

--CTE holds all the years starting from the oldest DB
;WITH    CTE        
          AS ( SELECT   DATEPART(YEAR, ( SELECT MIN(CreateTime)
                                         FROM   [DB]
                                       )) AS year
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   year + 1
               FROM     CTE
               WHERE    year < DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
             )
    SELECT  year ,
            COUNT(*) DBCount
    FROM    CTE
            LEFT JOIN [DB] ON CTE.year BETWEEN DATEPART(YEAR, [DB].Createtime)
                                       AND     DATEPART(YEAR,
                                                        [DB].LastCheckTime + 1)
    WHERE   [DB].LastCheckTime > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) -- filter only live DBs
    GROUP BY year;
```

And the result would be:

[image]